# Posting a Photo ( with caption ) to a FanPage Wall as a User using JavaScript SDK or Php SDK

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I would like to do the following:
As a user, post a photo ( with caption ) to a FanPage Wall such that 
on the FanPage Wall, I can see who ( which user ) have made that photo post.
( and also via the Graph API, i can see which user have posted the Photo, 
not via the Facebook App )

I would like to do it via the Graph API, either using the PHP sdk or JavaScript SDK.

How do i achieve the objective?

I have currently tried the following tutorials:
1) http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498/ 
This works, but the example is for posting a photo to a User Wall.
I changed the code such that the UserID (me ) is now the FanPage Id.
It works, ( since the user is the admin and have liked the FanPage ).
But the issue is that the photo does not show up on the wall. Instead it shows up 
with an attachment icon.

The following screenshot shows what i meant:
[image]

2) http://www.webspeaks.in/2011/12/upload-photos-to-facebook-fan-page.html
This works fine, but as the title says, it uploads photos to a album_id. I used the album_id of the Wall Photos, but after uploading the photo successfully, I am unable to find out
who ( which facebook user ) uploaded the photo.

However, if a facebook user logs into Facebook, like the FanPage, and posts to the FanPage Wall, i can find out which user made that post.

Any advice or suggestions?

Thanks a lot!

Best.

NOTE: the User is not an admin of the FanPage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is impossible to achieve, because to create a photo in a facebook page, you need to have manage_pages permission. It means you have to be the administrator of the page. All photos uploaded to facebook wall album are created on behalf of the page, not the user who upload them. You can see this using facebook graph explorer, examine the "from" field of the json result obtained from wall album.